# Find integer solution of sysem of quadratic equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, contest-math

If: $a,b,c$ positive integers, where $a\geq b\geq c$. such that: $$a^2 - b^2 - c^2 +ab=2011$$ $$a^2 +3b^2 +3c^2 -3ab-2ac-2bc=-1997.$$
Find the value of $a$

I tried, but I got nothing.

---

*Source: 2012 AMC 10A, Problem 24*

Comment: This looks like a contest problem. What's the source?

Comment: This is AMC 2012. I remember taking this.

Comment: Start with adding the two equations.

Answer (score 4):

Add the equations to obtain
$$ 14=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)=(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2$$
Up to permutation, the only way to write $14$ as sum of three squares is $14=3^2+2^2+1^2$ (note that the largest square cannot be $\ge 4^2>14$ nor $\le 2^2<\frac{14}3$). Using $a-c=(a-b)+(b-c)$ we conclude $c=a-3$, $b=a-1$ or $b=a-2$. Substitute this into the first equation to find
$$ 2011 = a^2-(a-1)^2-(a-3)^2+a(a-1)=7a-10$$
or 
$$ 2011 = a^2-(a-2)^2-(a-3)^2+a(a-2)=8a-13.$$
The only integer solution is $a=253$ from the second case.

Answer (score 2):

AMC-type problems *always* have some kind of symmetry in them, and algebra questions are designed to test your ability to see where factoring could be fruitful. The second equation looks like it has all the combinations of $a,b,c$, and the first equation looks like it just barely differs from the second. Indeed, if we add the equations and factor,
$$2a^2 + 2b^2 + 2c^2 - 2ab - 2ac - 2bc = 14,$$
$$a^2 - 2ab + b^2 + a^2 - 2ac + 2c^2 + b^2 - 2bc + c^2 = 14,$$
$$(a-b)^2 + (b-c)^2 + (c-a)^2 = 14.$$
We are given that $a,b,c$ are integers, so the squares of the differences must also be integers. Quick case work shows that $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 = 14$, and that all solutions are a permutation of $\{1,2,3\}$. We are also given that $a \geq b \geq c$ -- observing that $a - c = (a - b) + (b - c)$, we must have either Case 1 or Case 2, detailed below.

**Case 1:** $\;\;b = a - 1$ 
Substituting into the first equation, we have
$$a^2 - (a^2 - 2a + 1) - (a^2 - 6a + 9) + a(a - 1) = 2011$$
$$7a - 10 = 2011 \;\; \Rightarrow \;\; a \notin \mathbb{Z}$$

**Case 2:** $\;\;b = a - 2$ 
Substituting again, we have
$$a^2 - (a^2 - 4a + 1) - (a^2 - 6a + 9) + a(a - 2) = 2011$$
$$8a - 13 = 2011 \;\; \Rightarrow \;\; \boxed{a  = 253.}$$